# Solving recurrence using the iteration method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration, runtime, recurrence

I need help in solving T(n) = T(n/4) + T(n/3) + 2n using iteration method (recursion tree. I am thinking it would be either Θ(2n) or Θ(n)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward. We have two following inequalities:

```
T(n) > 2T(n/4) + 2n

and

T(n) < 2T(n/3) + 2n
```

Now, try to find upper bound and lower bound by expansion. Based on both cases, you will find that `T(n) = Theta(n)`.

For example, for `T'(n) = 2T(n/3) + 2n` we have the following expansion:

```
T'(n) = 2T(n/3) + 2n = 2^2 T(n/3^2) + (1 + 2/3) * 2n
```

By induction we can show that:

```
T'(n) = 2^log_3(n) T(0) + (1 + 2/3 + 2^2/3^2 + ...) * 2n  
      < n + 6 * n = 7n
```

Because `2^log_3(n) < 2^log_2(n) = n` and `(1 + 2/3 + 2^2/3^2 + ...)` is a geometric sum with factor `2/3`. Hence, the sum will be `1/(1-2/3) = 3` when `n` goes to infinity.

You can do the same analysis for the lower bound of `T(n)`.

Therefore, as `c1 * n <= T(n) <= c_2 * n`, we can conclude that `T(n)` is in `Theta(n)`.

Comment: how would I solve it using the iteration method?

Comment: @algor here, we solved it using the iteration method.